# Using SK3DNode to show a SceneKit particle object in SpriteKit

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, scenekit

I've seen that SceneKit contains a nice 3D starfield particle effect:

[image]

I've tried to use a SK3DNode to add this particle effect to my background.
Here's my code:

```
    import SpriteKit
    import SceneKit

    class GameScene: SKScene {

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
...

      addStarfield()
    }



    func addStarfield() {
        // create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene()

        // create and add a camera to the scene
        let cameraNode = SCNNode()
        cameraNode.camera = SCNCamera()
        scene.rootNode.addChildNode(cameraNode)

        // place the camera
        cameraNode.position = SCNVector3(x: 0, y: 0, z: 15)

        let ps = SCNParticleSystem(named: "Stars.scnp", inDirectory: "")
        scene.rootNode.addParticleSystem(ps)

        let starFieldNode = SK3DNode()
        starFieldNode.scnScene = scene
        starFieldNode.zPosition = -100
        self.addChild(starFieldNode)
    }
}
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work. I only see a gray background without stars. Also my normal SpriteKit sprites are no longer visible.

What have I done wrong?

Thanks for your help,
Stefan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The SpriteKit renderer doesn't support all the features of SceneKit, particularly those that can involve multipass rendering like particles, depth of field, and techniques. This is [probably a good bug to file](http://bugreport.apple.com).

Some possible workarounds, depending on what else is going on in your app:

- Use a physics field to make particles appear to flee from a center point, which should give you a similar starfield effect, especially if you couple it with a variation in particle scale over time.
- Instead of embedding a SceneKit scene in your SpriteKit view, embed a SpriteKit scene in a SceneKit view.

Comment: in the seccond approach I suppose I will not have to use SK3DNode right?